# Symfony4.2 form_login, после аутентификации возвращает 500

Tags: php, symfony4, failedlogin

После submit login формы, редирект не происходить,  и выдаются 500 ошибка. Регистрация проходит успешно, user сохраняется в базе, но с ним нельзя залогинится

```
 security.yaml
 security:
  encoders:
      App\Entity\User: bcrypt
  providers:
      database_users:
          entity: { class: App\Entity\User, property: username }
  firewalls:
      dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
      main:
          anonymous: ~
          pattern: ^/

          http_basic: ~

          form_login:
              check_path: security_login
              login_path: security_login
              csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
              default_target_path: micro_post_index


          logout:
              path: security_logout
              target: micro_post_index


SecurityController c логин методом

  class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
  /**
   * @var \Twig_Environment
   */
  private $twig;

  public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig)
  {
      $this->twig = $twig;
  }

  /**
   * @Route("/login", name="security_login", methods={"GET", "POST"})
   *
   * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
   */
  public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
  {
      return new Response(
          $this->twig->render(
              'security/login.html.twig',
              [
                  'last_username' => $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
                  'error' => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()
              ]
          ));
  }

MicroPostController c index методом
/**
* @Route("/")
*/
class MicroPostController
{
/**
   * @Route("/", name="micro_post_index")
   */
  public function index()
  {
      $html = $this->twig->render('micro-post/index.html.twig',
          [
              'posts' => $this->microPostRepository->findBy([], ['time' => 'DESC'])
          ]);

      return new Response($html);
  }
}

login.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
  {% if error %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
      </div>
  {% endif %}

  <form action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post">
      <div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-control-label required" for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" required="required" class="form-control"
                     value="{{ last_username }}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-control-label required" for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" id="Login" name="Login" class="btn-secondary btn">Login</button>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.get('redirect_to') }}">
      </div>
  </form>
{% endblock %}


Debug выдаёт 500
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/admin/Desktop/symfony41-web/symfony4_Project/symfony-01/website_skeleton/src/Entity/User.php on line 193
[Fri Mar 22 18:33:07 2019] 127.0.0.1:62093 [500]: /login - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/admin/Desktop/symfony41-web/symfony4_Project/symfony-01/website_skeleton/src/Entity/User.php on line 193

Эта строчка кода
/**
   * String representation of object
   * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
   * @return string the string representation of the object or null
   * @since 5.1.0
   */
  public function serialize()
  {
      return $this->serialize([
          $this->id,
          $this->username,
          $this->password
      ]);
  }

191. $this->id,


В чём может быть проблема?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)...
...Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in ...
```

Что именно здесь не понятно ?

Вам нужно увеличить количество выделяемой памяти для php. Сделайте это в php.ini в директиве memory_limit.
memory_limit = 1G и вам хватит :)